# Merge a commit from Develop to Master branch in the "successful git branching model"

Tags: git

In my project we're using [a successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). I've commited a bugfix to the Develop branch that I now want to hotfix into the Master branch. How can I do this without causing conflicts next time we merge from Development to Master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your commit. On `master`, run `git cherry-pick <commit-hash-id>`. `<commit-hash-id>` is unique within the repository, so it does not matter the commit is on a different branch.

This will not cause conflicts because git is smart enough to understand the commit has already been taken.